# JavaFx Application lags after time

Tags: java, javafx, lag, resource-leak

in my Application below, red blocks are falling from the top of the screen. My problem is, that after 3-5 minutes the animation begins to lag and I can't figure out why.
I used a profiler and found out, that it's not a memory leak but it must be a resource leak, I am pretty sure because the Cpu Load increases over time.
If you want to, you can just implement the necessary classes and compile and run the code, then you should probably see the problem. (after 3-5 minutes)
Thanks for your help and have a great day! :)

```
public class RBYDebug extends Application {

    Group root = new Group();
    ArrayList<Rectangle> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    Random random = new Random();

    int sW = 1600;  //screen Width
    int sH = 980;   //screen Height
    int dy = 4;     //vertical move speed

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage){

        //Setup Entities
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
            double x = random.nextDouble() * sW;
            double y = i * 50;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, -y -50, 50, 50);
            rect.setFill(Color.RED);
            entities.add(rect);
        }   
        //Root-Group setup
        root.getChildren().setAll(entities);

        //Setup Scene
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sW, sH, Color.BLACK);

        //Stage setup
        primaryStage.setTitle("RBY Debug");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

        //Setup Timer
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer(){
            public void handle(long now){
                update();
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    public void update(){

        for (Rectangle i : entities){
            if (i.getY() <= sH){
                i.setY(i.getY() + dy);
            }
            else {
                i.setY(-i.getHeight());
            }
        }
        root.getChildren().setAll(entities);
    }
}
```

Comment: A memory or resource leak might cause the behaviour described. Not that I readily see any in the code you’ve posted.

Comment: Can you post the Entity class? Maybe the game behaviour as well, as that might be the cause of the memory/resource leak.

Comment: I recommend you use Netbeans Profiler. Extremly usefull tool for  memory leaks, performance problems/tweaks